# Tem como gerar um número aleatório entre dois números em Java?

Tags: java, random

Como gera um número aleatório no java especifico entre min e max? Pois com a função nextInt da classe Random só pode especificar o max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) desta maneira

```
public int numeroAleatorio(int min, int max){

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

Ou usar a classe [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

```
public int numeroAleatorio(int min, int max){
    int randomNum = min + (int)(Math.random() * (max - min));

    return randomNum;
}
```

Comment: E essa lógica ai, tem como explicar ela? Achei interessante essa forma, mas não entendi seu funcionamento.

Comment: Estou justamente providenciando isso, @diegofm

Comment: Valeu @jbueno, era só deslocar o resultado final adicionando o min. Agora tem alguma diferença de performance entre essas duas classes?